# Помогите с проектированием?

Tags: веб-программирование, проектирование

Вообщем стоит задача: есть 2 открытых страницы в браузере, на обоих есть формы, однако они не зависимы друг от друга. Как  информацию из формы на одной странице перенести в форму на другой? Какую конкретную технологию веб-разработки лучше использовать? Возможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: localstorage там есть событие на обновление сторэджа (естественно только для нормальных браузеров) еще есть старый способ устроить трансфер кукой.(естественно всё на одном домене) http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут надо сервер (apache, nginx), серверный код и ajax (можно и без него). Схему можно оформить так - заполняем форму на одной странице, ajax отправляет данные на сервер. Ajax код на другой странице интересуется у сервера о новых данных и обновляет форму на другой странице.

Comment: Я могу вмешиваться только в код только на одной странице, т.е. изменение ни frontend ни backend второй страницы мне недоступны. Разве есть способ внедрить ajax на другую страницу, не прибегая к редактированию файлов на сервере?

Comment: ctrl+c ctrl+v. Более красивого решения, к сожалению, я не вижу.

Comment: Ну ок, решение не должно быть красивым, пусть уродливым, но избавлять пользователя от каких-либо манипуляций в браузере.

Comment: может плагин к браузеру, который делает работу по обмену данными?

Comment: > может плагин к браузеру, который делает работу по обмену данными?

Вполне возможно, мне нравится эта идея, но есть ли другие варианты? А что, если пойти с другой стороны: если бы существовал способ динамически скопировать код формы с другой страницы, то можно было бы отправить форму с клона...

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82
Случайно наткнулся на просторах интернета и о вашем вопросе вспомнил. Вроде в тему будет.